# Automate client addition of wireless network

Tags: windows, powershell, automation

I'm looking for a way to add a wireless network on a Windows 7 machine through Powershell or any other automated procedure. Has anyone done this with a Powershell script? This would save a lot of time in setting up a few hundred imaged machines I have to do. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NETSH scripts would work here, no? Take a look at the WLAN context.

-Oisin

Comment: @bstep - can you please mark my reply as the answer then? thanks.

Comment: Yep, sorry, new to this site!

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Managed Wifi API](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/) library available which I guess you can use from powershell.